# Issue with finding empty space to create acronym: nested for loops

Tags: javascript

I need to find an empty space to create an acronym, having issues with the first letter, the rest much easier..

```js
let word = "";
let p = "Tim Hortans Returant"


for (let i=0 ; i<p.length; i++){
    
    if (p.charAt(i) != " "){
        word+= i ; 
        }
        if(p.charAt(i) === " "){
            word+= p.charAt(i+1) 
            console.log(word)
    }
}
```

Comment: `let word = p[0];`

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by *'find an empty space'* -- can you elaborate on what you are looking for?

Comment: Hello, if given word is " Candy Cane" the output should be CC , if input is "     Candy    C        Cane" , output : CCC

Comment: Your query isn't clear enough. Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Means you need first char after each space?  "Tim Hortans Returant"
your desire output is HR right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split by spaces, map each word to its first character, then join:

```js
const p = "Tim Hortans Returant"
const word = p
  .split(' ')
  .map(word => word[0])
  .join('');
console.log(word);
```

Or, perhaps more efficiently, with a regular expression, capture the first character of each word, match the rest of the word, and replace with the captured character:

```js
const p = "Tim Hortans Returant"
const word = p
  .replace(/(\S)\S* */g, '$1');
console.log(word);
```

If you *had* to use a `for` loop (not recommended, it'll require verbose and messy code), add the `i + 1`th character to `word` when a space is found:

```js
const p = "Tim Hortans Returant";
let word = p[0];

for (let i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
  if (p[i] === ' ') {
    word += p[i + 1];
  }
}
console.log(word);
```

Comment: it has to use a loop,thats why I am trying nested for loops

Comment: Best to make all requirements clear in the question when you post it. See edit, concatenate the `i + 1`th character when the `i`th character is a space

Comment: I dont understand word=p[0]   why not let word = "";  , I dont know this method

Comment: That puts the first character of the input as the starting character of the abbreviation - without that, the loop won't identify the first character as the start of a word, and won't be able to concatenate it to the `word` variable. (just try removing it, you'll see that the resulting `word` is incorrect - it would result in `HR`, not `THR`)

Comment: See the other guy's answer, it looks like he's using the same code, except he didn't initialize `word` to `p[0]`, resulting in `HR` rather than `THR` (that's why you need `word = p[0]` at the start)

Comment: so, let me get this straight 

you use let word = p[0] , word containing the string, because you know, when you call the for loop to go over the string, because you are checking for empty strings, you need the first letter to be included , if there is an empty string in the first letter, it will just include an empty string

am I getting this right?

Comment: A character cannot be an empty string - an empty string has length 0, a character has length 1 (usually). The test is checking for *spaces* (`= ' '`), not empty strings. But `"Tim Hortans Returant"` does not have a space before the first word, so the acronym variable is initialized to the first character of the input, `T`